# Centering a barcode into a longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, longtable, barcodes

I try to center horizontally a barcode into my longtable, but I don't success it.

Actually I'm trying to put the barcode juste before the (missing at the moment) page number (this page number is normally at the bottom of the page), all of that centered horizontally.

Here is what I have now :
[image]

And here is an MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
 \usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{array,longtable}
  \usepackage{pst-barcode}
 \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
  \font\myfont=cmr12 at 21pt
 \title{}
 \usepackage{layout}
 \usepackage[nomarginpar, margin=0.7in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{plain}

\newcommand{\newPart}[1]{
\part*{#1}
\markright{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}


\newcommand{\newSection}[1]{
\section*{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}
\markright{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}}

 % pour afficher dans le "toc", des lignes en pointillées entre les chapitres des livres et leur numéro de page.
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

 % suppress page number in toc for parts
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\usepackage{sectsty}\sectionfont{\normalfont\large\underline}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \definecolor{corrected}{rgb}{0.0, 0.62, 0.38}
 \definecolor{error}{rgb}{0.8, 0.25, 0.33}
 \definecolor{no_change}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
 \setmainlanguage{french}
 \setotherlanguage{greek}
 \newfontfamily\greekfont{Arial}
\newcommand\Pheader{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}
\newsavebox\TBox
\def\textoverline#1{\savebox\TBox{#1}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\rule[1.1\ht\TBox]{\wd\TBox}{0.7pt}}

\usepackage{pageslts}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nospace}[1]{\nofrench@punctuation\texttt{#1}\french@punctuation}
\makeatother
\let\oldtabular\tabular\renewcommand{\tabular}{\large\selectfont\oldtabular} 

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{gospelbook}
\setcounter{gospelbook}{1}
\newcommand{\mygospelbook}[1]
{\setcounter{gospelchapter}{1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}#1}

\newcommand{\agospelbook}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}\mygospelbook{#1}}

\newcounter{gospelchapter}
\newcommand{\mygospelchapter}{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thegospelchapter}\LARGE\bfseries\thegospelchapter\refstepcounter{gospelchapter}}

 % for finals N
\newcommand{\finalN}[1]{\textoverline{#1~~}}
 \newcommand{\finalNedit}[3]{\color{#3}{\textoverline{\color{#2}{#1}~~} }}  


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
%\foreignlanguage{greek}{\tableofcontents}
\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}
\newgeometry{margin=0.0in}
\clearpage

 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}

\Large
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{cc|l|cc}
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\mygospelbook{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον}} \textbf{(\nospace{1:1})} } \\ \\ [-1em] 
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
&  & &  & \\ [-0.9em]
 \mygospelchapter &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βιβλοϲ γενεϲεωϲ \textoverline{ιυ} \textoverline{χυ} υιου δαυειδ} & 6 &  \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{υιου αβρααμ αβρααμ εγεννηϲεν τον} & 3 & \textbf{2} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιϲαακ ιϲαακ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ια} & 9 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{κωβ ιακωβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ιουδαν} & 14 &  \\
& 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και τουϲ αδελφουϲ αυτου ιουδαϲ δε} & 2 & \textbf{3} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον φαρεϲ και τον ζαρα} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εκ τηϲ θαμαρ φαρεϲ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 14 &  \\
& 15 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζρωμ εζρωμ δε εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 20 &  \\
& 21 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{αραμ αραμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αμινα} & 5 & \textbf{4} \\
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαβ αμιναδαβ δε εγεννηϲεν τον} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νααϲϲων νααϲϲων δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ϲαλμων ϲαλμων δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{5} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον βοοζ εκ τηϲ ραχαβ βοοζ δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 11 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ωβηδ εκ τηϲ ρουθ ωβηδ} & 17 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δε εγεννηϲεν τον ειεϲϲαι ιεϲϲαι δε} & 2 & \textbf{6} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον δαυειδ τον βαϲιλεα} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{δαυειδ δε ο βαϲιλευϲ εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲολομωντα εκ τηϲ του ουριου ϲολο} & 1 & \textbf{7} \\
& 1 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μων δε εγεννηϲεν τον ροβοαμ} & 5 &  \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ροβοαμ δε εγεννηϲεν τον αβια αβι} & 11 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{α δε εγεννηϲεν τον αϲα αϲα δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{8} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον ιωϲαφατ ιωϲαφατ δε} & 7 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εγεννηϲεν τον ιωραμ ιωραμ δε εγ\finalN{ε}} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νηϲεν τον οζειαν οζειαϲ δε εγεννη} & 3 & \textbf{9} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιωαθαμ ιωαθαμ δε εγεννη} & 8 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αχαζ αχαζ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον εζεκιαν εζεκιαϲ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{10} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον μαναϲϲη μαναϲηϲ δε εγεννη} & 8 &  \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αμων αμων δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ιωϲιαν ιωϲιαϲ δε εγεννηϲεν τ\finalN{ο}} & 4 & \textbf{11} \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\begin{pspicture}(0, 0in)
\parbox[b][1in]{1.5in} {
\centering
    \psbarcode{http://ntvmr.uni-muenster.de/community/modules/papyri/?zoom=11&left=5&top=-5&site=INTF&image=20032/0/10/10/2}{}{pdf417}
}
\end{pspicture}
\\
\newpage
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{ευαγγελιον κατα μαθθαιον} \textbf{(\nospace{1:11})} } \\ \\ [-1em] % Si on veut ajouter les bordures latérales, remplacer {7}{c} par {7}{|c|}
\cline{3-3} \\
\cline{3-3}
 & &  &  & \\ [-0.9em]
& 5 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιεχονιαν και τουϲ αδελφουϲ αυτου} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{επι τηϲ μετοικεϲιαϲ βαβυλωνοϲ} & 13 &  \\
\textbf{12} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μετα δε την μετοικεϲιαν βαβυλωνοϲ} & 5 & \\
& 6 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιεχονιαϲ εγεννηϲεν τον ϲαλαθιηλ} & 9 &  \\
& 10 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲαλαθιηλ δε εγεννηϲεν τον ζορο} & 14 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{βαβελ ζοροβαβελ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 3 & \textbf{13} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον αβιουδ αβιουδ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ελιακιμ ελιακιμ δε εγεννη} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον αζωρ αζωρ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 3 & \textbf{14} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ϲαδδωκ ϲαδδωκ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον αχειν αχειν δε εγεννηϲεν} & 13 &  \\
& 14 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ελιουδ ελιουδ δε εγεννηϲεν} & 3 & \textbf{15} \\
& 4 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ελεαζαρ ελεαζαρ δε εγεννηϲ\finalN{ε}} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{τον ματθαν ματθαν δε εγεννη} & 13 &  \\
& 13 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιακωβ ιακωβ δε εγεννη} & 3 & \textbf{16} \\
& 3 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲεν τον ιωϲηφ τον ανδρα μαριαϲ} & 8 &  \\
& 9 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{εξ ηϲ εγεννηθη \textoverline{ιϲ} ο λεγομενοϲ \textoverline{χϲ}} & 15 &  \\
\textbf{17} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{παϲαι ουν αι γενεαι απο αβρααμ ε} & 7 & \\
& 7 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ωϲ δαυειδ γενεαι δεκατεϲϲαρεϲ} & 10 &  \\
& 11 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και απο δαυειδ εωϲ τηϲ μετοικε} & 16 &  \\
& 16 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲιαϲ βαβυλωνοϲ γενεαι \textoverline{ιδ}} & 19 &  \\
& 20 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και απο τηϲ μετοικεϲιαϲ βαβυλω} & 24 &  \\
& 24 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{νοϲ εωϲ του \textoverline{χυ} γενεαι \textoverline{ιδ}} & 29 &  \\
\textbf{18} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του δε \textoverline{ιυ} η γενεϲειϲ ουτωϲ ην} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{μνηϲτευθειϲηϲ γαρ τηϲ μητροϲ αυ} & 12 &  \\
& 12 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{του μαριαϲ τω ιωϲηφ πριν η ϲυνελ} & 18 &  \\
& 18 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{θειν αυτουϲ ευρεθη εν γαϲτρι εχου} & 23 &  \\
& 23 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ϲα εκ \textoverline{πνϲ} αγιου} & 26 &  \\
\textbf{19} &  & \foreignlanguage{greek}{ιωϲηφ δε ο ανηρ αυτηϲ δικαιοϲ ων} & 7 & \\
& 8 & \foreignlanguage{greek}{και μη θελων αυτην παραδιγματιϲαι} & 12 &  \\
[0.2em]
\cline{3-3}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you reduce your document to just the longtable with plain text (instead of greek letters) and the bar code? My guess is that many people here (like me running Linux) cannot process your document because of some irrelevant things like a missing font. It also seems that most packages and definitions are not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to center the barcode in the middle column, I presume.

Then you need to measure it, because the barcode is typeset as an object with zero width and height. Then you need to remove the rule on the left and on the right, which can be done with `\multicolumn`.

```
\cline{3-3}
&\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{%
  \makebox[5.5cm][l]{% the width is about 5.5cm
  \rule{0pt}{2cm}% the height is about 2cm
  \psbarcode{http://ntvmr.uni-muenster.de/community/modules/papyri/?zoom=11&left=5&top=-5&site=INTF&image=20032/0/10/10/2}{}{pdf417}%
}}
\\
\newpage
\cline{3-3} \\ [-1em]
```

[image]